# absolutely positioned DIV not showing on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is the simplified style for a blog hosted at wordpress.com. The code is validated CSS, yet IE won't show it correctly (that are not really news, are they?). In particular, the upper menu (#primary div) can't be seen in IE, rendering the blog pretty unusable.

The easy solution would be to change div orders, but as the style is given by wordpress, the restriction on this problem is you can only change the css code, not the html.

Can you guys figure out an easy override to IE's presentation quirks? I've read that this may be related by hasLayout properties, but i'm not proficient on web design.

```
<HTML><HEAD >

<style type="text/css">

div#wrapper {
width:1000px;
background:#fff url('http://embolsados.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/bg.png') repeat-y 50% 0;
margin:0 auto;
}

div#header {
text-align:center;
background:#ddd;
color:#eee;
width:980px;
height:333px;
position:relative;
left:10px;
margin:0;
}

div#container {
float:left;
position:relative;
left:10px;
top:0;
width:630px;
font-size:.9em;
line-height:1.8em;
padding:30px;
}

#primary {
background:#32a855;
width:980px;
position:absolute;
top:333px;
text-indent:15px;
border:0;
margin:0 0 0 10px;
padding:0;
}

#secondary {
float:right;
overflow:hidden;
width:270px;
position:relative;
left:-10px;
top:0;
padding:10px;
}

div#footer {
background:#32a855 url('http://embolsados.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/footer.png') no-repeat;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
clear:both;
height:40px;
padding-top:25px;
position:relative;
}

div#footer a {
color:#fff;
}
</style>

</HEAD>


<BODY>
<DIV id=wrapper>

<DIV id=header>Title</DIV>

<DIV id=container>

    <DIV id=content>Content.</DIV>
</DIV>

<DIV class=sidebar id=primary>Upper menu.</DIV>

<DIV class=sidebar id=secondary>Side menu.</DIV>

<DIV id=footer>Footer</DIV>

</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: unrelated note, but non-xhtml syntax makes kittens sad

Comment: But having to serve XHTML up as text/html and having to dance around the compatibility guidelines makes bunnies sad. Then the ducklings get sad at the less expressive power of XML DTDs leading to reduced usefulness of validators. All in all, XHTML leads to more sadness among cute animals than HTML does.

Comment: I avoid coding for IE until I'm happy with the design in firefox. The I do a separate style sheet for IE. I'm not answering, because it's hard to put a finger on exactly why IE does what it does. I believe there's a toolbar for IE like Firefox's Firebug.

Comment: What is the version of IE that exhibits such behavior?

Comment: Even worse, though is when god kills a kitten everytime tables for layout is used.

Comment: Ok folks, indeed it was XHTML but i cut a lot of unrelated code from the page: extra css, javascript, metas, etc. The error still persists on the code i posted.

Comment: Ie is a sticker for the doctype tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way other than removing the float property on the sibling elements or as you stated, change the source order.. possibly wrap a div around the AP.

Comment: It seems there is no solution for this. I'll be very glad to change to another more correct answer should that not be the case!!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is your issue

http://www.brunildo.org/test/IE_raf3.html

In short add an empty `<div></div>` between the floated element and the abs positioned element.  It's ugly but it's the only thing i found that worked.

Comment: +1 for solving this problem for me, i had the benefit of being able to modify the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add following line to the #primary styles section:

`*display: expression(style.display='block', 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the absolutely positioned element in a non-floated div does the trick.

http://www.daharsh.net/tech/2008/10/ie6-or-ie7-position-absolute-not.htm